# Flutter doesn't auto format code when adding new widget, even after adding comma (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When I add new widget on top of another widget using **alt+enter** shortcut, flutter doesn't auto format it even after adding comma at the end.

Former Code:

```
Expanded(
  child: Image.asset("images/dice2.png"),
)
```

After adding new Widget:

```
Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(child: Image.asset("images/dice2.png")),
)
```

After adding comma and pressing **ctrl+s**, it doesn't auto-format it:

```
Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(child: Image.asset("images/dice2.png"),),
)
```

After pressing **ctrl+alt+L**, it **does** auto-format it

```
Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
    child: Image.asset("images/dice2.png"),
  ),
)
```

Am I missing something?

PS: **ctrl+s** is the hot reload shortcut that also performs auto-formatting for other code.

Comment: until there are some error you cant reformat your code.

Comment: there are no error at all. and alt ctrl L auto formats it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to File>Settings>Languages&Frameworks>Flutter and under the Editor, switching on these two options

[image]

PS: Rest of the code doesn't require these options to be checked and performs auto-format without needing these options to be checked. But, its best to have these options checked in order to avoid facing the same issue I faced.